# In Scala, how to get a slice of a list from nth element to the end of the list without knowing the length?

Tags: scala

I'm looking for an elegant way to get a slice of a list from element n onwards without having to specify the length of the list. Lets say we have a multiline string which I split into lines and then want to get a list of all lines from line 3 onwards:

```
string.split("\n").slice(3,X)       // But I don't know what X is...
```

What I'm really interested in here is whether there's a way to get hold of a reference of the list returned by the `split` call so that its length can be substituted into `X` at the time of the `slice` call, kind of like a fancy `_` (in which case it would read as `slice(3,_.length)`) ? In python one doesn't need to specify the last element of the slice.

Of course I could solve this by using a temp variable after the split, or creating a helper function with a nice syntax, but I'm just curious.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Just drop first n elements you don't need:

```
List(1,2,3,4).drop(2)
res0: List[Int] = List(3, 4)
```

or in your case:

```
string.split("\n").drop(2)
```

There is also paired method `.take(n)` that do the opposite thing, you can think of it as `.slice(0,n)`.

In case you need both parts, use `.splitAt`:

```
val (left, right) = List(1,2,3,4).splitAt(2)
left: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
right: List[Int] = List(3, 4)
```

Comment: .drop does not work. .takeRight is the correct answer.

Comment: @Ara I disagree, .drop does it's intended purposes, if you want to take the right N elements, you just drop the left len-N elements. Also after looking into how takeRight is implemented, it simply calls .drop.

Answer (score 94):

The right answer is `takeRight(n)`:

```
"communism is sharing => resource saver".takeRight(3)
                                              //> res0: String = ver
```

Comment: Considering the OP question this doesn't do the right thing as it takes the n elements starting from the end.
`List(1,2,3,4).takeRight(3)` produces `List[Int] = List(2,3,4)`

Answer (score 10):

You can use scala's list method 'takeRight',This will not throw exception when List's length is not enough, Like this:

```
val t = List(1,2,3,4,5);
t.takeRight(3);
res1: List[Int] = List(3,4,5)
```

If list is not longer than you want take, this will not throw Exception:

```
val t = List(4,5);
t.takeRight(3);
res1: List[Int] = List(4,5)
```

Answer (score 4):

get last 2 elements:

`List(1,2,3,4,5).reverseIterator.take(2)`

Comment: Is that the only way to get the last 2 w/o knowing the # of elements?

Comment: List(1,2,3,4,5).reverse.take(2).reverse to get in original order