# Getting two last elements of the list WITHOUT using reverse method? [scala]

Tags: scala

How can I get two last elements of the list **without** using reverse method in Scala? (only first, second, tail, head). I wanted to type sth like "list.tail.head" but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Scala, how to get a slice of a list from nth element to the end of the list without knowing the length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259250/in-scala-how-to-get-a-slice-of-a-list-from-nth-element-to-the-end-of-the-list-w) see second answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't want to use anything like reverse, takeRight etc...

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
@tailrec
def take2[T](l: List[T]): Option[List[T]] = l match {
  case Nil | _ :: Nil => None
  case _ :: _ :: Nil => Some(l)
  case _ :: xs => take2(xs)
}
```

If you have an algorithm that needs fast access to the last two elements in a collection consider something other than List.

Answer (score 4):

Just use takeRight

```
List(1, 2, 3).takeRight(2)
res0: List[Int] = List(2, 3)
```